# How to access the WSDL URL of a OSB proxy service in web browser

Tags: wsdl, osb, oracle-service-bus

Does anybody know how to access the `WSDL` URL of a `Oracle Service Bus`?

For example, in tomcat, axis2 if a service is deployed I can access the WSDL of it like:

`http://localhost:8080/services/foo?wsdl`

**How to achieve the same in OSB?**

P.S.: I have installed `OSB` in `Weblogic`.

Answer (score 7):

You access it the same way. To verify the path to your wsdl, login to the OSB console:

```
http://localhost:7001/sbconsole
```

Click Resource Browser on the left and you should see all of the available proxies you have deployed and their paths. If you click on one of the proxies, you will see your Endpoint URI:

```
Endpoint URI    /service/test/YourService
```

If you add ?WSDL onto the end of that, you should be able to access your WSDL like:

```
http://localhost:7001/service/test/YourService?WSDL
```

Assuming your managed server is running on your localhost with that port.

Comment: I follow the steps. I could not view them. Are you sure it is ?wsdl at the end. It depends on the container isnt it?

Answer (score 4):

Quoting from the OSB Documentaton:

There are three ways to access an effective WSDL:

- In a Web browser, enter the URL for an HTTP-based proxy service,
  appended with ?WSDL. This works only for HTTP-transport-based services for which Oracle Service Bus can generate effective WSDLs.)
- In a Web browser, enter the fixed HTTP URL, for example:

  ```
   [http://host:port/sbresource?PROXY/project_path/proxy_service_name]
  ```

  or

  ```
   [http://host:port/sbresource?BIZ/project_path/business_service_name]
  ```

  This works for all services for which Oracle Service Bus can generate effective WSDLs.
- Export the WSDL from the console