# What is the full WSDL endpoint url

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, weblogic

I have a wsdl content which shows the `Service` element like below.

```
<service name="CheckIn">
    <port name="CheckInSoap" binding="s0:CheckInSoap">
        <soap:address location="http://10.50.130.93:16200/_dav/cs/idcplg" />
    </port>
</service>
```

I want to the access the WSDL url like `http://ip:port/../..?wsdl` from the server `10.50.130.93`. I have tried the url `http://10.50.130.93:16200/_dav/cs/idcplg?wsdl` and `http://10.50.130.93:16200/_dav/cs/idcplg/CheckIn?wsdl` . But both them doesn't show the `WSDL` content I expected. So my question is what exactly the endpoint url of WSDL it is ? Is there any reason stop to display the `WSDL` from the urls ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually this `<soap:address location="http://10.50.130.93:16200/_dav/cs/idcplg" />` is just a way of documenting where the service can be accessed. The real endpoint depends on where you deploy the service in your code (or someone). So you should look in the code or ask service provider where the service with required WSDL is deployed.

Also not all SOAP providers gives you WSDL by adding `?wsdl` prefix to service endpoint, java CXF for example can do this but others may not.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your WSDL is part of a deployment, try the following:

- Log in to the admin console
- Click Deployments
- Find your deployment
- Click Testing tab

You should find a test point with the full URL to your service (if everything was set up correctly initially).

Perhaps even more useful is the Weblogic documentation on [Browsing to the WSDL of the Web Service](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14571_01/web.1111/e13758/setenv.htm#WSGET144) Specifically read up on `contextPath`, which refers to the context root of the Web service

If you're using the Weblogic OSB, reference: [How to access the WSDL URL of a OSB proxy service in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649819/how-to-access-the-wsdl-url-of-a-osb-proxy-service-in-web-browser)