# obtain WSDL from Oracle Service Bus for a proxy service

Tags: wsdl, soapui, osb, oracle-service-bus

I need to find the WSDL of a proxy service that I have defined in the Oracle Service Bus.

Export WSDL option in the console gives me jar file which contains the .WSDL file but in a different format,

```
<WL5G3N0:definitions name="PollAddressFromDB-concrete" targetNamespace="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/DBPoll_Adapter/PollAddressFromDB/PollAddressFromDB" xmlns:WL5G3N0="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:WL5G3N1="http://xmlns.oracle.com/pcbpel/adapter/db/DBPoll_Adapter/PollAddressFromDB/PollAddressFromDB" xmlns:WL5G3N2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">
```

I want to run a test on my web service using Soap UI but Sap UI would not accept this WSDL format.

How and Where can I retrieve the actual WSDL file.

Thanks!

Comment: Often, but not always, the WSDL is at `http://endpoint?wsdl` - note the question mark, **not** a dot!

Comment: Just remember to uncheck security options like Basic Auth when you load the WSDL, or SoapUI may fail to download the associated schemas. You can re-enable it afterwards, since it's cached in the project file.

Answer (score 1):

As SiKing mentioned, if it's a http proxy, just go to the endpoint URL and append `?wsdl` to the end. SoapUI can create a project from that.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to my following answer [How to access the WSDL URL of a OSB proxy service in web browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649819/how-to-access-the-wsdl-url-of-a-osb-proxy-service-in-web-browser/20669645#20669645)

Reproducing it here:

There are three ways to access an effective WSDL:

- In a Web browser, enter the URL for an HTTP-based proxy service,
  appended with ?WSDL. This works only for HTTP-transport-based services for which Oracle Service Bus can generate effective WSDLs.)
- In a Web browser, enter the fixed HTTP URL, for example:

  ```
   [http://host:port/sbresource?PROXY/project_path/proxy_service_name]
  ```

  or

  ```
   [http://host:port/sbresource?BIZ/project_path/business_service_name]
  ```

  This works for all services for which Oracle Service Bus can generate effective WSDLs.
- Export the WSDL from the console