# SAP SOAMANAGER ping to Oracle Service Bus webservice endpoint fails

Tags: web-services, ping, osb, sap-basis

After some while to put all the pieces together for a Java 8 simulation of the SAP SOAMANAGER Web Service Ping (see SAP Knowledge Database #1947516), I had to face, that the Oracle Service Bus v11.1.1.7 (running on WebLogic Server v10.3.6.0) just seems to to support the used HEAD method but only GET.

*NOTE: I had to exchange httpS with httpX due to newbie restrictions ;)*

The outcome of the following code of "Ping.java" is

> Trying to perform a HTTP 'GET' on 'httpX://pelican.xxx.de:42/aua_xxx?wsdl'
>
> response: code '200' / message 'OK'
>
> Trying to perform a HTTP 'HEAD' on 'httpX://pelican.xxx.de:42/aua_xxx?wsdl'
>
> response: code '500' / message 'Internal Server Error'

```
import java.lang.System;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.URL;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;

/**
 * to be able to use SSL you have to add the root certificate to the java keystore:
 * keytool.exe -import -noprompt -trustcacerts -alias rootca2015 -file rootca2015.cer -keystore D:\jdk\jre\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit
 * 
 * ...and then use THIS java instance when calling the class:
 * D:\jdk\jre\bin\java Ping https://host.de:4242/test user123 pass123
 */

public final class Ping {

    private static void request(final String url, final String user, final String pass, final String protocol)
    {

        System.out.println("\nTrying to perform a HTTP '" + protocol + "' on '" + url + "'");


        HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = null;


        try
        {
            httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        }
        catch (java.net.MalformedURLException mue)
        {
            System.out.println("\nMalformedURLException: " + mue);
            System.exit(42);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("\nIOException: " + ioe);
            System.exit(42);
        }



        if ( user != null )
        {
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestProperty ("Authorization", "Basic " + java.util.Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(((new String(user + ":" + pass)).getBytes())));
        }


        try
        {
            httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod(protocol);
        }
        catch (java.net.ProtocolException pe)
        {
            System.out.println("\nProtocolException: " + pe);
            System.exit(42);
        }


        int responseCode = 0;
        String responseMessage = null;


        try
        {
            responseCode = httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode();
            responseMessage = httpUrlConnection.getResponseMessage();
        }
        catch (java.net.UnknownHostException uhe)
        {
            System.out.println("\nUnknownHostException: " + uhe);
        }
        catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            System.out.println("\nIOException: " + ioe);
            System.exit(42);
        }


        System.out.println("\nresponse: code '" + responseCode + "' / message '" + responseMessage + "'");

    }

    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {

        if ( args.length < 1 || args.length == 2 || args.length > 3 )
        {
            System.out.println("\nUSUAGE: java HeadPing URL [username password], for example java Ping https://host.de:4242/test user123 pass123\n");
        }

        String url=args[0];

        String user=null;
        String pass=null;

        if (args.length == 3 )
        {
            user=args[1];
            pass=args[2];
        }

        System.out.println("\nINFO: response code for HTTP_OK is '" + HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK + "'!\n");

        request(url, user, pass, "GET");
        request(url, user, pass, "HEAD");

        System.exit(42);
    }

}
```

**Does anyone has a solution for this problem? Is the SAP SOAMANAGER able to use GET? Can the HEAD capability added to the OSB?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSB 11G has REST support. It's primitive compared to 12C, but you can switch based on `$inbound/ctx:transport/ctx:request/http:http-method/text()` etc. The OSB service will need to be written to accept the particular REST operation to be meaningful.

However, you're *not even calling* the OSB endpoint. You're calling the URL that [auto generates a WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16649819/how-to-access-the-wsdl-url-of-a-osb-proxy-service-in-web-browser) of the service.

Remove the `?wsdl` and you'll get the response you actually want.

Comment: Well, sorry for the (now) obvious mistake with the `?wsdl` :(

Comment: BTW: It's about pinging good old plain web services, no REST.

Comment: But the best thing is... _IT WORKS!_ :D

Comment: `D:\OSB-Ping via SAP>java Ping https://pelican.xxx.de:42/aua_xxx xxx xxx`

Comment: `Trying to perform a HTTP 'GET' on 'https://pelican.xxx.de:42/aua_xxx'`

Comment: `Trying to perform a HTTP 'HEAD' on 'https://pelican.xxx.de:42/aua_xxx'`

Comment: So THANKS A LOT, @TrentBartlem. Now I can give the ball back to our SAP operators ;)

Comment: PS: Sorry... [code/pre indentation markdown](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) seems not to work in my comments. What am I doing wrong?